# Born Circumcised

Tags: brit-milah

We know that Iyov, Adam, Shes, Noach, Shem, Yaakov, Yosef, Moshe, Shmuel, Dovid, Kalev ben Dovid, & Yirmiyahu were all born circumcised (which is a very rare occurrence). My nephew was also just born circumcised, does this signify that he has a particularly lofty & holy neshama? Also do we know of more recent Tzaddikim who were born circumcised?

[Avos D'R Nosson, Ch.2](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.2.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אלא מלמד כשיצא **איוב** ממעי אמו יצא מהול. ולא איוב בלבד יצא מהול אלא
> אף **אדה"ר** נברא מהול שנ' ויברא אלהים את האדם בצלמו. אף **שת** נולד
> מהול שנ' ויולד בדמותו כצלמו. ואף **נח** יצא מהול שנ' נח איש צדיק תמים.
> ואף **שם** יצא מהול שנ' **ומלכי צדק** מלך שלם. ואף **יעקב** יצא מהול
> שנ' ויעקב איש תם. ואף **יוסף** יצא מהול שנ' ואלה תולדות יעקב יוסף והלא
> אינו ראוי לומר אלא תולדות יעקב ראובן. אלא שכשם שיעקב יצא מהול כך יוסף
> יצא מהול. אף **משה** יצא מהול שנ' ותרא אותו כי טוב הוא. אלא מה ראת אמו
> של משה שהוא נאה ומשובח מכל בני אדם אלא מלמד שראת אמו יצא כשהוא מהול.
> אף **בלעם** יצא מהול שנ' נאם שומע אמרי אל. אף **שמואל** יצא מהול שנ'
> והנער שמואל הולך וגדול. אף **דוד** יצא מהול שנ' מכתם לדוד. אף **כלאב
> בן דוד** יצא מהול שנ' חכם בני ושמח לבי ואשיבה חורפי דבר. אף **ירמיה**
> יצא מהול שנ' בטרם אצרך וגו'. אף **זרובבל** יצא מהול שנ' ביום ההוא נאם
> יוי צבאות אקחך זרובבל וגו' כל המהולים ט"ו

A slightly different list is quoted in [Midrash Tehillim (Mizmor 9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tehillim.9.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ה אחד מי"ג שנולדו מהולים, ואלו הן. אדם הראשון שת **חנוך** נח שם **תרח** יעקב
> יוסף משה שמואל דוד **ישעיה** ירמיה

Comment: Are you sure he was born fully circumcised ?

Comment: Who is we that knows this? How do they know it?

Comment: Belated welcome to this site. You may want to link a source to support your first sentence. Avot Derav Natan, among other areas, mentions this in one of the earlier chapters.

Comment: Avos D'R Nassan Ch 2

Answer (score 5):

The [Minchas Elozor](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=3309#p24702) (Munkatcher Rebbe, also a famous *mohel*) quotes a number of sources who posit that although we find people who are born *somewhat* circumcised, nobody today is born *completely* circumcised. He does, however, bring conflicting reports. [See link for further definition; see also Avnei Nezer YD 334.7]

R' Yisroel Belsky [reported](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=3309#p458084) having officiated over a case of someone born completely circumcised.

Regarding one who actually is born completely circumcised - the Shl"a (Shvuos, Torah Or) writes:

> דהוא שלימות כח הגוף בלי התבטל כוחותיו ויחלשו. וכן מצינו דוגמא לזה
>   באברהם, קודם שנימול כתיב (שם יז, יז) 'ויפול אברהם על פניו', אבל אחר
>   שנימול לא. ומשה רבינו ע"ה שנולד מהול, לא נתבטל לגמרי ממנו שום כח
>   והרגש.

Comment: Can you add a translation of the Shl”a’s quote, for those who can’t read Hebrew?

Answer (score 2):

In Sefer Hamidos it states:

> ה. מִי שֶׁנּוֹלַד מָהוּל, בְּיָדוּעַ שֶׁכּחַ הַמְדַמֶּה שֶׁלּוֹ טוֹב
>   וְיָפֶה.
>
> 5. One who is born circumcised, it is certain that his power of imagination is good and proper.

Sorry, I do not know of any recent Tzaddikim who were born circumcised.

Comment: It's not exactly a question people ask each other. "Hey, were you born circumcised?"

Answer (score 1):

I once asked this question of a very famous mohel.  He said the people you listed were born mohul.  However, no one nowadays is born that way.  There may be just a little skin, but everyone has something and needs a bris.

Comment: Welcome, TIDE. Thank you for your contribution! When possible, it's helpful to add sources, or at least details. What was the name of the Mohel you asked?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya TIDE and thanks for this first answer. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I believe even people born fully circumcised like Dovid Hamelech still had to have a bris

Answer (score -3):

It appears that the reason why no one is born circumcised anymore, is because they remove much more skin than they used to. Anyone think this has something to do with it?

Comment: What would your source for this be?

Comment: Priah or the uncovering of the glans in its entirety was a man made addition to the commandment to discourage jewish men from restoring their foreskins.

Comment: According to the Talmud (Yevamos 71b) the Jews were  later COMMANDED to do Priah. Tosfos (ad loc. s.v. Lo Nitnah) posits that this obligation always existed; its source being Halacha Le'Moshe Me'Sinai.