# People born circumcised?

Tags: midrash, brit-milah

In [this discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37884/did-adam-and-eve-have-bellybuttons-fingerprints-or-ridge-over-lip), it's stated: "There is a minor tractate in the Talmud called Brit Millah which lists all the people born circumcised."

Can anyone point me towards a copy of this tractate (which doesn't appear in Bar Ilan's list of minor tractates) or towards other sources which contain a list of people born circumcised/ more recent sources which discuss this list?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=SO1DAQAAMAAJ&pg=PP73&lpg=PP73&dq=%22%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA+%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%22&source=bl&ots=Q-6U-xDloZ&sig=ACfU3U03a1VIt6RMjpSwOQztN89rRptWHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4qIT494LuAhUPGVkFHbKEBv0Q6AEwDnoECBAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%22&f=false

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104182/759

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in [Avot De-Rabbi Natan 2:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D%27Rabbi_Natan.2.5?lang=bi): Born circumcised were Adam, Seth, Noah, Shem, Jacob, Joseph, Moses, the wicked Balaam, Samuel, David, Jeremiah and Zerubbabel.